# Java how to SetSelectedItem the ComboBox if from database?

Tags: java, netbeans, combobox

I have tried this, but failed. if I set manually the ComboBox from properties, I can set the selected item to that one.

```
cbSetNoInvoice.setSelectedItem(txtSearchAll.getText());
```

and this one is for load the listComboBox

```
for (Transaction tr : listTransaction) {
cbSetNoInvoice.addItem(tr.getNo_invoice());
```

[Here is the screenshot. I want to set the selected item on the "Invoice" combobox if user input on the textfield and click the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RI0E.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to bind the value in the comboBox to a value in the database? I'm not clear on what you're trying to achieve here

Comment: It's like a temp on the list, so I could removeItem if the value on jTextField is same as in the list after I saved.
so it won't appear for twice if I have selected...
that's all I want

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (I haven't tested this out)

```
btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String text = txtSearch.getText();
        int index = cbInvoice.getModel().getIndexOf(text);
        if (index == -1) {
            // the text is not already in the combobox
            cbInvoice.insertItemAt(text, 0);
            cbInvoice.setSelectedIndex(0);
        } else {
            // the text is already there
            cbInvoice.setSelectedIndex(0);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: yes, kind of, but while search it won't insert which is not already in the combobox..., but I can't execute cbInvoice.setSelected cause probably the item is not string when first added?